# How to find indices of elements in 2D array - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I've had a problem that's been giving me a hard time as I am new to Swift. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

I have a 2D array of CellState : [[CellState]] and I am trying to find all the indices of the elements that are .alive. Indices should be returned as [[Int]] as follows:

```
var cellStates = [ \\initial 2D array
                    [.dead, .alive, .alive], 
                    [.alive, .dead, .dead]
                 ] 
var coordinatesOfAliveCells = [ \\2D array that I need
                                 [0,1],
                                 [0,2],
                                 [1,0]
                              ]
```

In other words, getting the coordinates of every .alive in the cellStates 2D array.

Thanks!

Comment: [[0,2],[1,0]] corresponds to the "coordinates" of the .alive elements. So [0,2] means first row (index 0) and third column (index 2) or in other words third element in the first array.

Comment: What if there is more than one `.alive` value in a given subarray? What if there is no `.alive` in a given subarray?

Comment: If there is more then it gives the position of the second one (for example: [[0,1],[0,2]]) and if there is no .alive then it returns nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the cell states and map the results:

```
enum DeadOrAlive {
    case dead
    case alive
}
var cellStates: [[DeadOrAlive]] = [[.dead, .dead, .alive], [.alive, .dead, .dead], [.alive, .dead, .alive], [.dead, .dead]]
let indicesOfAliveCells = cellStates.enumerated()
    .map { top in top.element.enumerated()
        .filter { $0.element == .alive }
        .map { [top.offset, $0.offset] } }
    .filter { $0.count > 0 }
    .flatMap { $0 }
print(indicesOfAliveCells)
```

Output:

> [[0, 2], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 2]]

This returns an index pair for each instance of `.alive` found in each of the subarrays.

Comment: Hey, I have another question unrelated to this one concerning segues. I'd really appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` operator to transform each element

`let coordinateArray = coordinateTuples.map { [$0, $1] }`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `[$0.0, $0.1]`

Comment: Sorry to bother, I edited the question a bit too late.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Interesting. I never noticed that before. Both forms work.

Comment: @rmaddy iirc `$0/$1` not working and having to use `$0.0` was a bug, it was fixed but I'm assuming both forms were left in to avoid breaking existing code.